# Cannot Connect from remote client to kafka server on digital ocean

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to test the connectivity from one environment, in to a digital ocean drop running our kafka server.

I'm attempting to run `./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <HOST_NAME>:9092 --topic <topic>`

And I'm consistently getting

```
[2017-10-17 14:38:59,438] WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2017-10-17 14:38:59,490] WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2017-10-17 14:38:59,542] WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2017-10-17 14:38:59,644] WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2017-10-17 14:38:59,696] WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Steps taken so far:

- Setting the advertised.listeners to `PLAINTEXT://<ipaddress>:9092`
- Adding  to the /etc/hosts of every client trying to connect
- Adding the advertised.host and advertised.port
- 9092 is accepting TCP connections inside the ubuntu installation on the digital ocean drop
- Kafka is running on IPv4 instead of IPv6

Relevant section of my server.properties file (HOST_NAME is an alias for the actual host name to preserve privacy):

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://HOST_NAME:9092
host.name=HOST_NAME
# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://HOST_NAME:9092
advertised.host.name=HOST_NAME
advertised.port=9092
```

I can connect from the localmachine to itself, but I'm at the end of my rope for how to get a dumb little test message to come across the wire.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: firewall rules? Should you allow ingress traffic to port 9092?

Comment: I should have said that as well, I added a firewall rule in Ubuntu.  Is there a specific digital ocean firewall I need to set it up as well?

Comment: Not sure because I have no experience with Digital Ocean but they should set firewall rules by default. Take a look at [this blog](https://blog.digitalocean.com/cloud-firewalls-secure-droplets-by-default/)

Comment: We're not using their cloud firewalls.  I added ports in the iptables specific to our environments, and it still won't connect.

Comment: Can you telnet to <HOST_NAME>:9092?

Comment: I could not, for the reasons in my self-answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by modifying the iptables config on my remote host by adding this rule to my iptables config:

```
-A INPUT -s [hosts went here] -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9092 -j ACCEPT
```

I had to allow TCP connections to port 9092 on the remote host.  Our infrastructure team blocks all but specific ports in our development environment which was blocking dev from using telnet.

To summarize: Open the ports on your remote kafka server, with an iptable configuration.  Confirm your localhost can send tcp connection data to that port.